# Problema Bootstrap com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap-3

Tenho um código HTML que ao inserir a classe `form-control` no input, minha função JavaScript não funciona.

Assim não funciona minha função soma:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">        
      <label class="col-md-3"><b>IEM1 Investimento na Planta</b></label>                       
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">Total</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IEM1_a" id="IEM1_a" value="0,00" readonly class="form-control resultado_soma 16 decimal" size="21" maxlength="21" title="Valor total em reais de capital aplicado incluindo rede de transporte de telecomunicações, equipamentos, software, hardware e serviços.">
         </div>                       
      </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">Marketing/<br>Propaganda</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IEM1_b" id="IEM1_b"  value="0,00" class="form-control fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em Marketing/Propaganda">
         </div>       
      </div>                
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">Equipamentos</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IEM1_c" id="IEM1_c"  value="0,00" class="form-control fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em equipamentos">
         </div>                       
      </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">Software</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IEM1_d" id="IEM1_d"  value="0,00" class="form-control fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em software">
         </div>                       
      </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">P&D (Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento)</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IEM1_e" id="IEM1_e"  value="0,00" class="form-control fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em P&D (Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento)">
         </div>         
      </div>              
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">Serviços</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IEM1_f" id="IEM1_f" value="0,00" class="form-control fator_soma 16 decimal"  maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em serviços">
         </div>                       
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
         <label class="col-md-3">Call-Center ou qualquer tipo de central de atendimento</label>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input  type="text" name="IEM1_g" id="IEM1_g" value="0,00" class="form-control fator_soma 16 decimal"  maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em Call-Center ou qualquer tipo de central de atendimento">
         </div>                       
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Assim funciona:

```
  <div class="container">



   <div class="row">        
    <label class="col-md-3"><b>IEM1 Investimento na Planta</b></label>                       
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Total</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_a" id="IEM1_a" value="0,00" readonly class="resultado_soma 16 decimal" size="21" maxlength="21" title="Valor total em reais de capital aplicado incluindo rede de transporte de telecomunicações, equipamentos, software, hardware e serviços.">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Marketing/<br>Propaganda</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_b" id="IEM1_b"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em Marketing/Propaganda">
    </div>       
    </div>                
    </div> 

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
   <label class="col-md-3">Equipamentos</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_c" id="IEM1_c"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em equipamentos">
    </div>                       
</div>
    </div> 


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
   <label class="col-md-3">Software</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_d" id="IEM1_d"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em software">
    </div>                       
</div>
    </div> 



    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">P&D (Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento)</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_e" id="IEM1_e"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em P&D (Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento)">
    </div>         
    </div>              
    </div> 

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Serviços</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_f" id="IEM1_f" value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal"  maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em serviços">
    </div>                       
    </div>
</div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Call-Center ou qualquer tipo de central de atendimento</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input  type="text" name="IEM1_g" id="IEM1_g" value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal"  maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em Call-Center ou qualquer tipo de central de atendimento">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
</div>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
      $(".decimal").keypress(function(){
        if(this.type == "text" && this.className != "numero_livre"){
        if(this.value.length > 1){
            if(isNaN(this.value.replace(",", ".")) == false){
                if((this.value.indexOf("0") == 0) && (this.value.indexOf(",") != 1)){
                    this.value = this.value.substring(1);
                }
            }
        }
        }
       });

       $(".fator_soma").keypress(function(){
        if(this.type == "text" && this.className != "numero_livre"){
        if(this.value.length > 1){
            if(isNaN(this.value.replace(",", ".")) == false){
                if((this.value.indexOf("0") == 0) && (this.value.indexOf(",") != 1)){
                    this.value = this.value.substring(1);
                }
            }
        }
        }
       });

       $(".numero").keypress(function(){
        if(this.type == "text" && this.className != "numero_livre"){
        if(this.value.length > 1){
            if(isNaN(this.value.replace(",", ".")) == false){
                if((this.value.indexOf("0") == 0) && (this.value.indexOf(",") != 1)){
                    this.value = this.value.substring(1);
                }
            }
        }
        }
       });

       $(".decimal").change(function(){
       if(this.value.indexOf(",") < 0){
        this.value = this.value + ",00";    
       } else {
        if(this.value.split("").reverse().join("").indexOf(",") == 1){
            this.value = this.value+"0";
        }
        if(this.value.split("").reverse().join("").indexOf(",") > 2){
            this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(",", ".")).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
        }
       }

       });

       $(".fator_soma").change(function(){
        var resultado = 0;
        var classeArr = "";
        var parte = "";
        classeArr = this.className.split(" ");
        parte = classeArr[1];
        $(".fator_soma."+parte).each(function(){
            resultado = parseFloat(this.value.replace(",", ".")) + parseFloat(resultado);
        });     
        $(".resultado_soma."+parte).each(function(){
            this.value = resultado;
            if(classeArr[2] == "decimal"){
                this.value = this.value.replace(".", ",");
            }
        });
       });
            });
```

Alguma sugestão de como fazer o primeiro caso funcionar com a função JavaScript?

Comment: Seria interessante ter o código javascript para ver como você está acessando os campos.

Comment: irei Postar!!!!

Comment: tenta colocar a classe form-control no final, porque você está usando concatenação ali, acessando os campos na ordem que a classe está apontada.

Comment: jogue o form-control depois do fator_soma 16

Comment: Nos meus testes, colocando no final funciona perfeitamente. html publicado como resposta abaixo.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou! Sou novo em web...agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocando o `form-control` no final, funcionou nos meus testes.

O que ocorre é que você está usando um identificador concatenado no `className`, portanto o `form-control` no começo quebra a sequencia pois você inicia o caminho por `fator_soma`

```
 <div class="container">



   <div class="row">        
    <label class="col-md-3"><b>IEM1 Investimento na Planta</b></label>                       
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Total</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_a" id="IEM1_a" value="0,00" readonly class="resultado_soma 16 decimal form-control" size="21" maxlength="21" title="Valor total em reais de capital aplicado incluindo rede de transporte de telecomunicações, equipamentos, software, hardware e serviços.">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Marketing/<br>Propaganda</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_b" id="IEM1_b"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal form-control" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em Marketing/Propaganda">
    </div>       
    </div>                
    </div> 

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
   <label class="col-md-3">Equipamentos</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_c" id="IEM1_c"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal form-control" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em equipamentos">
    </div>                       
</div>
    </div> 


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
   <label class="col-md-3">Software</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_d" id="IEM1_d"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal form-control" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em software">
    </div>                       
</div>
    </div> 



    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">P&D (Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento)</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_e" id="IEM1_e"  value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal form-control" maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em P&D (Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento)">
    </div>         
    </div>              
    </div> 

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Serviços</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IEM1_f" id="IEM1_f" value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal form-control"  maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em serviços">
    </div>                       
    </div>
</div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Call-Center ou qualquer tipo de central de atendimento</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input  type="text" name="IEM1_g" id="IEM1_g" value="0,00" class="fator_soma 16 decimal form-control"  maxlength="21" size="21" title="Valor total em Reais de capital aplicado em Call-Center ou qualquer tipo de central de atendimento">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
</div>
```